# Divs with content auto width and also parent of div auto width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html look :

```
<div class="right fly" style="top: 45px;">
<div class="dataContainer">
    <div class="fuelLvlInfo">
        <div class="header"><i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>Paliwo - poziomowskaz</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="usage"><div class="n"><span>Zużycie [l]:</span></div><div class="v">24</div></li>
            <li class="lvl"><div class="n"><span>Poziom paliwa [l]:</span></div><div class="v">---</div></li>
            <li class="avgUsageKm"><div class="n"><span>Śr. zużycie [l/100km]:</span></div><div class="v">46.4</div></li>
            <li class="avgUsageHour"><div class="n"><span>Śr. zużycie [l/h]:</span></div><div class="v">---</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="fuelflowInfo">
        <div class="header"><i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i>Paliwo - przepływomierz</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="usage"><div class="n"><span>Zużycie [l]:</span></div><div class="v">1</div></li>
            <li class="avgUsageKm"><div class="n"><span>Śr. zużycie [l/100km]:</span></div><div class="v">1.9</div></li>
            <li class="avgUsageHour"><div class="n"><span>Śr. zużycie [l/h]:</span></div><div class="v">---</div></li>
            <li class="counter"><div class="n"><span>Licznik [l]:</span></div><div class="v">---</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is preview:

[image]

What i need:  make to `.right` be auto width, and divs in `li` must be 50% width or width equal to the longest `div.n` content.

Tried white-space:nowrap; display:inline-block etc. not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/eta71Lbx/

Preview what i expect :

50% width
[image]
or width fixed to content length (on left side or right side)
[image]

Comment: What is this *supposed* to look like?

Comment: Edited with preview images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the span element that will shrink the with based on the content. I would avoid using span. 
But if you need to use it, then here is a work around to solve the .right part of the menu using jQuery.

- Remove the 50% at the `> div { width:50%; }`
- Add `white-space:nowrap;` to
  the `.n` class.
- (If you already included jQuery after the list is created, then
  don't do this step). Include jQuery: 
  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">`
- Add the folowing to the ready or inside a function you want:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {var maxWidth = 0;$( "li .n" ).each(function( index ) {var w = parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));if(maxWidth<w){maxWidth = w;}});var m = maxWidth + 'px';$( ".n" ).css('width', m);});
  ```

https://jsfiddle.net/eta71Lbx/3/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Forgot to mention, that will dynamically set the width of the biggest to the rest. Of course, you can add max-width and min-width (with the correct overflow) to avoid issue with large texts.

Comment: It's no way to do it pure CSS? I have dynamic data in this divs so pure css would much faster

Comment: The thing is the way you're creating the table. At some point, after the values are added, you need to calculate the width of the biggest cell at the right and make the same size for the rest. You can do an html table in order to accomplish that with pure css.

Comment: At [this link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGdgLp) you can see an html sample (needs modifications to fit in your project) without JS, pure css. Hope that helps!